# In redis when bull queue locked in nodejs? and how to solve this issue?

Tags: node.js, redis, bull-queue

I'm using Redis 3.0.504, and store job id sometimes queues are not executed, and the **lock ** queue,when bull queue locked in nodejs?

localhost:6380> get "bull:myqueue queue:2524:**lock**"
"c145f8af-852b-433e-9400-13e09419553d"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring this to the link

[Lock Functionality](https://httpshttps://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/issues/660)

[Bull Doc](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull)